# Code that will shuffle songs that are selected

Tags: matlab, function, shuffle

As the title shows, I'm trying to write a code that shuffles a list of songs chosen by the user. I succeeded with all the parts but the one that shuffles the songs, it seems that the code does nothing at all when it's supposed to shuffle the list of songs. Below is the code where Z is a cell array containing all the tracks' names chosen by the user, and V is also a cell array containing all the tracks available that can be chosen by the user. I just need some help with completing this code or even changing it all if needed. By the way myoffset is just a value chosen by the user also through input, my friend told me to use it but I don't get why so if it gets in your way just ignore/delete it.

```
function shuffled=theSpotifyShuffle(Z, myOffset)    
Z=strcat('Track',L,':',V(result)');     
U1=unique(Z);     
Numbsongs = zeros(size(U1)); 
for i = 1:length(U1)  
Numbsongs(i) = sum(strcmp(chosen,U1(i)));
end 
for j=1:length(T) 
for i = 1:length(U1)
 if Numbsongs(i)==1 
     myOrder(Numbsongs)=rand(1);
else Numbsongs(i)> 1;
 N=Numbsongs(i);
 for n=1:N
     myorder(i)=(n/(N+1)*(1+myOffset*randn(1)));
 end
 end
 end
 end
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`randperm`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) to generate the shuffled indices and use them to get shuffled `Z`.

```
shuffled = Z(randperm(numel(Z)));
```